# Languages as dropdown menu, Joomla! 3.1

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, joomla

I have a website on Joomla! 3.1 where I want the languages to be displayed as a drop-down menu not with `<select>` element, but in `<ul>`-s and `<li>`-s as ordinary drop-down menu. The active language `<li>` has a class of 'lang-active'. In the template overrides I added some class for inactive `<li>` also with the class name of 'lang-inactive'. But I don't manage to put all 'lang-inactive' `<li>`-s into a nested `<ul>` tag to have something like an ordinary drop-down menu.

I want the structure to be like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="lang-active><a href="#"></a></li>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="lang-inactive"><a href="#"></a></li>
      <li class="lang-inactive"><a href="#"></a></li>
      <li class="lang-inactive"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Below is the code for template override.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

```
<ul class="<?php echo $params->get('inline', 1) ? 'lang-inline' : 'lang-block';?>">
 <?php foreach ($list as $language) : ?>
  <?php if ($params->get('show_active', 0) || !$language->active):?>
   <li class="<?php echo $language->active ? 'lang-active' : 'lang-inactive';?>" dir="<?php echo JLanguage::getInstance($language->lang_code)->isRTL() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' ?>">
     <a href="#"></a>
   </li>
  <?php endif;?>
 <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

This is the full code with link that gives me inaccurate results when one language is active. Sometimes there are two English and one Spanish on my front end and sometimes there are the three of the languages. I wonder where the problem is.

```
<ul class="<?php echo $params->get('inline', 1) ? 'lang-inline' : 'lang-block';?>">
 <?php
    $active = false;
    foreach($list as $k => $language){
        if ($language->active) {
            $active = $language;
            unset($list[$k]);
        }
    }

 if ($params->get('show_active', 0) && $active !== false) : ?>
    <li class="lang-active" dir="<?php echo JLanguage::getInstance($active->lang_code)->isRTL() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo $language->link;?>">
            <?php if ($params->get('image', 1)):?>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('image', 'mod_languages/' . $language->image . '.png', $language->title_native, array('title' => $language->title_native), true);?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php echo $params->get('full_name', 1) ? $language->title_native : strtoupper($language->sef);?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
    </li>
<?php endif;?>

    <ul class="submenu">
<?php foreach ($list as $language) : ?>
        <li class="lang-inactive" dir="<?php echo JLanguage::getInstance($language->lang_code)->isRTL() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $language->link;?>">
            <?php if ($params->get('image', 1)):?>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('image', 'mod_languages/' . $language->image . '.png', $language->title_native, array('title' => $language->title_native), true);?><span><?php echo $language->title_native;?></span>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php echo $params->get('full_name', 1) ? $language->title_native : strtoupper($language->sef);?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the active language before creating the list.

```
<ul class="<?php echo $params->get('inline', 1) ? 'lang-inline' : 'lang-block';?>">
 <?php
    $active = false;
    foreach($list as $k => $language){
        if ($language->active) {
            $active = $language;
            unset($list[$k]);
        }
    }

 if ($params->get('show_active', 0) && $active !== false) : ?>
    <li class="lang-active" dir="<?php echo JLanguage::getInstance($active->lang_code)->isRTL() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' ?>">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
<?php endif;?>

    <ul class="submenu">
<?php foreach ($list as $language) : ?>
        <li class="lang-inactive" dir="<?php echo JLanguage::getInstance($language->lang_code)->isRTL() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' ?>">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

This will create a single list active item (if the list is configured to display it) and a sub-list with the rest of the inactive items.

Of course, you need to add the actual content to the list (links, images etc.) for it to be visible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But there is a little bit more to be done here. As soon as I add the links I sometimes get two of same languages, I consider active language link should be written not the same way as inactive? I will edit now the final result I have, in case you find some solution to overcome the problem), Thanks a lot

Comment: The active language is stored in `$active`, not in `$language`, that stores the last iterated language from the last `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks very much, I've just found the solution myself.